# Phaser: How to set a fallback for this.image.load

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am fetching images from URL, sometimes it fails with the message below.

```
GET https://the/image/url::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

This is not caused by Phaser *( although I don't know the exact reason. This can be fixed by re-fetching the files. )*, but since I am only using Phaser, I want to add a fallback to Phaser's load API when this happens.

Below is the API I use to load an image.

```
this.load.image('image_key', 'https://the/image/url')
```

As the [document](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Types.Loader.html#.XHRSettingsObject) says, we can add xhrSetting to the third parameter such as async.

```
this.load.image('image_key', 'https://the/image/url'), {async: true}`
```

However, I need a fallback to handle my fetching problem (reload the page/re-fetch the files when it fails, otherwise the image will be a green box.), is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by adding a listener to `loaderror` event, you can find which file has failed

```
function preload ()
{
    this.load.on('loaderror', (reqinfo)=>{
        console.log(reqinfo);
    })
}
```

you can find more details [here](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Loader.Events.html#event:FILE_LOAD_ERROR)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added this code to my application, but I can't see if it works immediately since the problem not happen often.
I will report here when the problem happens.

Comment: add a wrong url to load, then you can test this code

Comment: You are a genius! This listener works well for my need. Thank you!